# Загрузка файла из интернета в переменную

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Необходимо, используя файл из интернета (например, http://example.ru/baza.txt), записать его в какую-либо переменную и дальше работать с этой переменной. Желательно не использовать никаких библиотек (сторонних, из интернета), а пользоваться стандартными.

---

### Какие функции можно использовать для реализации вышеизложенного?

Если не сложно, укажите подключаемые библиотеки при вызове этой функции (`#include "example"`).

---

Использую IDE Visual Studio 15 с набором средств v140.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - `wininet.h` из коробки. Функция [InternetReadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103(v=vs.85).aspx), примеров использования - навалом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать использовать из `Urlmon.h` следующую функцию:

```
HRESULT URLDownloadToFile(
             LPUNKNOWN            pCaller,
             LPCTSTR              szURL,
             LPCTSTR              szFileName,
  _Reserved_ DWORD                dwReserved,
             LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK lpfnCB
);
```

Т.е. алгоритм такой: скачиваете данные в какой-либо файл, а затем уже работаете, как вам привычно с файлом. Хоть в "переменную" его сохраняйте, хоть что хотите делайте.

За справкой, обратитесь в MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Не подходит, идет скачивание файла на компьютер, для пользователя это плохой сигнал. Мне бы только в память

Comment: @Кастиэль, для пользователя это плохой сигнал, если это вирус :) А так, есть, как минимум, всякие каталоги `Temp`, как-раз для таких целей. А если ваш файл эдак пару-тройку гигабайт? ;)

Comment: Вдобавок, есть всякие `CreateFileMapping` для отображения файлов в память.